# Why UI-less fragment is null in onResume sometimes

Tags: android, android-fragments, onresume

I have UI-less fragment `portfolioArrayFragment`, with `setRetainInstance(true)`

However, under very rare circumstance, it will become null sometimes in `onResume`. I get once a while crash report from Google Developer Console. I had tried several ways to reproduce the crash but not able to make it.

---

1. Keep rotating the device. `onCreate` and `onResume` will be triggered.

---

1. Press HOME button.
2. Long press HOME button. Select the app. `onResume` will be triggered.

---

1. Press HOME button.
2. Launch 5 other apps.
3. Long press HOME button. Select the app. `onCreate` and `onResume` will be triggered.

---

Even though, I still not able to get a null `portfolioArrayFragment` during `onResume`. Any idea why such case happens so?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final FragmentManager fm = this.getFragmentManager();
    this.portfolioArrayFragment = (PortfolioArrayFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(PORTFOLIO_ARRAY_FRAGMENT);
    if (this.portfolioArrayFragment == null) {
        this.portfolioArrayFragment = PortfolioArrayFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(this.portfolioArrayFragment, PORTFOLIO_ARRAY_FRAGMENT).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } else {
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    // SOMETIMES, this.portfolioArrayFragment IS NULL AND I HAVE NO IDEA WHY?!

    if (this.portfolioArrayFragment.buyArray == null) {
        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, getBuyArrayLoaderCallbacks());                
    } 

}
```

Comment: Pressing home button will save the state , your activity is just paused, it will not make your instance null.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all code from **onCreate** method and add it to **onResume** Since onResume methods calls every time when an application/activity is first time loaded or it resumed.

Comment: We just do not want to blindly solve this problem without understanding why (Why UI-less fragment is null in onResume sometimes). Note, moving code to `onResume` will not work, as we need to access ui-less fragment in `onCreateView` too. `onCreateView` is triggered before `'onResume`, and after `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding new fragment in

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(this.portfolioArrayFragment, PORTFOLIO_ARRAY_FRAGMENT).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

**[From android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29)**

> The commit does not happen immediately; it will be scheduled as work
>   on the main thread to be done the next time that thread is ready.

So you will get NULL in onResume() in case your fragment transaction is still pending, What you can do is try running fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions() after committing your transaction but before finding by tag and see if that works for you.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the transaction is being executed. Even the transaction is not being executed during `onResume`, the member variable `this.portfolioArrayFragment` is already being initialized with non-null reference.

Comment: hmmm..then it can be a case of out of memory,where while creating new instance you got oom error. any views??